# Goto an anchor via javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, anchor

I'm trying to create a function in JavaScript which will take the user to a HTML anchor. The only thing is, I'm trying to create it in SharePoint within an .aspx page...

I have a hidden table, which I unhide with a JavaScript function, but the table is at the bottom of the page, so I added an anchor next to the table and tried to hyperlink to it... but it's not working... This is my code:

```
function GoTo() {
    window.location.hash="change"
}

<a name="change"></a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called correctly?

Comment: By the way, you should terminate your statements with semicolons.

Comment: This is what I've got...
A button, which is 
'  <input type="button" value="Request For Change" onClick="GoTo()">  '
  the function, which is: '  <script language="JavaScript">function GoTo() {window.location.hash="change"}</script>   '
  and the anchor:   '<a name="change"></a>

Comment: Can you show us a page in which it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `window.location.hash = "change"` to `window.location.href = "#change"`
I've tested this and this is working in IE8, Chrome, FF, Safari.

There is probably another way:

```
function scrollToAnchor(anchorName){
  //set the hash so people can bookmark
  window.location.hash = anchorName;
  //scroll the anchor into view
  document.getElementsByName(anchorName)[0].scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

If the hash method is not working try to set your window in a small size that it can jump to the hash tag

Comment: Wrong. Although the `#` character is required in the URL, it is not part of the `hash` property.

Comment: Just to post again, as you posted after I did:

That's not working, Gregoire. The code is now:

function GoTo() {window.location.hash="#change"}

But it's still not working... no JavaScript errors, by the way. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it something that SharePoint might be blocking by any chance??

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and it worked for me.  Try adding `#change` to the address bar and see whether it does what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

JD-Daz -

Based on your brief spec, I created this simple test page, and it seems to work.  Maybe you should do a copy and paste of your own page into a new page, and then cut stuff out until it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function GoTo() {
            var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            myTable.style.visibility = "visible";
            window.location.hash = "change";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:GoTo();">Click Here</a><br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
11<br />
12<br />
13<br />
14<br />
15<br />
16<br />
17<br />
18<br />
19<br />
20<br />
21<br />
22<br />
23<br />
24<br />
25<br />
26<br />
27<br />
28<br />
29<br />
30<br />
<table id="myTable" border="1" width="500" style="visibility:hidden" backcolor="black">
    <tr>
        <td>Shown</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a name="change"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how I had it. I created a test page and it worked perfectly fine. As soon as I placed it into SharePoint, it stopped working. I changing an ASPX page and inserting custom JavaScript, CSS and HTML - I've had no problem with it before, until this... and I have no idea why. Thank's for the effor though Mark, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, change to button to

```
<input type="button" value="Request For Change" onclick="GoTo(); return false;">
```

The problem is that an `input type="button"` will submit the page when clicked.  Therefore, when you click it, it scrolls down to your anchor element, but then reloads the page, defeating the purpose.  You need to add `return false` to the end of the `onclick` handler to suppress the default action.

Also, `onclick` should be all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `<a href="#change" onclick="unhide table code here">link text</a>`.